# Scheduling a task from within a task - good practice?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a daily 'Dinner Ready' event that is supposed to happen at say at 15:00, but sometimes it is delayed and happens at 15:05, or 16.20 etc.

I want to setup a task 'Check Dinner Status' that is run periodically, starting 3 hours before the expected Dinner Ready event, and running at defined intervals until Dinner is Ready. The interval between how often I check dinner gets shorter and shorter the closer I get to dinner time.

What is the best way to setup this schedule?  It is fairly simple to setup the next CheckDinnerTask from within the one that is just running.  But is this a good practice?

The code below is based on [Spring Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), but I'm open to any scheduling framework.

```
scheduler.schedule(new CheckDinnerTask(), new CronTrigger("* 0 12 * * *"));

public class CheckDinnerTask() implements Runnable {
  run() {
      if (isDinnerReady() == false)
      {
          // Find out how long until scheduled dinner and 
          int mins = getMinutesToExpectedDinnerTime(); 
          mins /= 2;
          if (mins < 5) 
             mins = 5;
          // Reschedule this task from here?
          scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new CheckDinnerTask(), mins*60*1000);

      }
      else 
      {
          eatDinner();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The main problem with a recursive task is that if there is any bug in the recursion it will spam tasks.
Could you precise which scheduling API you use? Can't it be extended to support the complex scheduling schema you want to use?

Comment: @Guillaume - question updated to clarify I'm currently using Spring Scheduling, but I'm open to any framework.